# Reload a page on "Go To Previous Page"

Tags: php, javascript, refresh, page-refresh

when I'm going to the previous page of my mobile website, I Would like to refresh the page just on time.

When I'm adding the code below in my javascript script, it refresh the page all the time.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.reload();
    </script>
```

I tried this in my php doc:

```
<body onload="document.refresh();">
```

But, still doesn't work.
Any ideas?

I would like to refresh it because I'm modifying the opacity of the ".transparent_font" class  on hover.
Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //window.location.reload();
    //$(".transparent_font").css({'opacity' : '0'});
    //$(".thumbnail_image_related_project .transparent_font").css({'opacity' : '0'});

        $(".thumbnail_image_related_project").hover(
            function(){
                $(this).children(".transparent_font").stop().animate({'opacity' : '0.7'}, 300); 
             },
            function(){
                $(this).children(".transparent_font").stop().animate({'opacity' : '0'}, 300); 
           }
        );
    });
```

Comment: Why do you need to refresh the page when going back? Going back is a page refresh... seems there is some other problem that needs to be fixed.